# can we send window message to window service

Tags: winapi, service

I have created a window service in C++, and have created a window with message loop in that.

From a separate process I am trying to get the handle to the window which I have created in service.

I am not getting window handle.
please help me to know whether it is possible to have a window in service.

Regards
Ashish

Answer (score 3):

Services typically run in a different session, and thus in a different workstation/desktop, than other processes.  Window access cannot cross desktop boundaries, which is why you cannot find the window or send it messages even if you could find it.  You need to re-think your design.  For simple messages without parameters, you can use `ControlService()` to send custom control codes to your service handler callback.  For more complex messaging, use an IPC (inter-process communication) mechanism instead, such as a named pipe, mailslot, or socket.